# Зеркальное отображение MovieClip

Tags: flash, actionscript

Доброе время суток. Не подскажите, есть ли возможность во flash зеркально отобразить `movie clip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- в младших версиях флеш плеера, от 10-й, можно крутануть по оси Z
- отрисовать в битмап, BitmapData.draw(); и отзеркалить его, правда свойства мувиклипа полностью пропадут
- по уму нужно искать другое решение, в зависимости от задачи, например: параметрический визуальный объект

Comment: А можно по подробнее о третьем варианте? Или слова чтоб, загуглить..? 
У меня стоит задачаЖ есть муви клип ходьбы человека, что бы он пошел в обратную сторону нужно его развернуть. Как это можно сделать.?

Comment: тертий вариант - довольно абстрактная штука, тут нужно смотреть на конкретные требованию к объекту, ПРИМЕРНО выглядит так: объект разбивается на запчасти, которые рисуются кодом или спрайтами, причем рисуются в двух фиксированных положениях, зеркально/незеркально, в зависимости от внешних требований, примерно так

Comment: Спасибо, очень подошел 1й вариант) 2мерная картинка сделал rotation по Y.

Comment: `el._width = -1 * el._width;` уже не катит?)

Comment: Простите, не совсем понял.. Что из этого выйти должно.?
moveClip.width = -1*moveClip.Width - ни чего не произошло..

Comment: А не подскажите из за чего может искажаться изображение при повороте на 180 по y, при перемещении клипа по экрану.?

Comment: вместо el._width = -1 * el._width; уже не катит
может имелся ввиду scaleX/scaleY ?
_width - это из второго action script

искажение будет из за того, что это "true" 3D преобразование объекта
для супер-правильного зеркального отображения, нужно рисовать объект программно

еще это может быть связанно со сглаживанием, но я думаю у вас оно включено

Answer (score 0):

_xscale=-_xscale